# Why does iOS look at the following as a NSDictionary and not an array?

Tags: ios, nsarray, nsdictionary

```
{
 "success":true,
 "listings":
 {
   "50831582253b4acf09000000":
   {
     "id":"50831582253b4acf09000000",
     "title":"fddfds",
     "assets":[],
     "discussions":[]
   }
 },
 "displaymessage":"1 Listings Found"
}
```

I am still struggling between dictionaries and arrays. What would make the above an Array?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a pretty big difference between dictionaries and arrays. Dictionaries store data entries in relation to a keys you specify on instantiation. For example:

```
NSDictionary *myDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"object1",@"key1",@"object2",@"key2", nil];
```

This alloc/inits a dictionary and sets "object1" for "key1" and "object2" for "key2", so then if you wanted to ask for the value of "key1" you could access it with the following.

```
NSLog(@"%@",[myDictionary objectForKey:@"key1"]);
```

Objects in a dictionary can be arrays, dictionaries, booleans, data, dates, numbers and strings.

On the other hand, arrays store data by the datas index within the array:

```
NSArray *myArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"object1",@"object2",@"object3", nil];
```

You can then access the a specific bit of data from within the array by asking for `objectAtIndex:`, ex:

```
NSLog(@"%@",[myArray objectAtIndex:1]);
```

Which will return "object2" because the first index in an array is always "0".

Answer (score 2):

Check the [JSON](http://www.json.org/) docs

JSON Arrays are represented by square brackets

```
[ "object1", "object2" ]
```

JSON arrays are normally represented in Objective-C by `NSArray`. This matches up with the new literal syntax

```
@[ @"object1", @"object2" ]
```

JSON Objects are represented by curly brackets

```
{ "key" : "value" }
```

JSON objects are normally represented in Objective-C by `NSDictionary`. This also matches up with the new literal syntax

```
@{ @"key" : @"value" }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can probably tell, the entities or "cells" in the list are separated by commas (,)

In a serialized dictionary, an entity is broken into a key:value pair by a colon (:)

```
"success":true
```

Where the first part in quotes before the colon is the key, and the second part is the value that corresponds to that key.

A serialized array might look something like this:

```
{"hello", "goodbye", "world", "words", "friendship"}
```

Notice that entities are still separated by commas, but there are no colons outside of quotes.

Another key difference is that in dictionaries, keys must be unique, so you shouldn't have something like this:

```
{"success":true, ..., "success":false}
```

whereas in an array, elements do not have to be unique:

```
{"hello", "hello", "goodbye"}
```

Hope this helps =)

Comment: The difference is not really in commas vs. semi-colons.

Comment: ... it's colons vs. no colons. Not sure where you saw semicolons, H2CO3.

Comment: @H2CO3 - Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean - referring to commas vs. semi-colons (I know you mean colons) is not how I explained the difference between dictionary and array. The asker posted a dictionary in serialized JSON, so I explained what makes it a dictionary in serialized form, and I showed what a serialized array would look like in contrast.

Comment: @sampson-chen I see, and no, I didn't mean colons. I meant semi-colons (";"). But I'm not sure OP is not asking about the problem the other way around.